# I changed repetitive awk expressions into one function

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I had a 8 awk expressions that only differed by 2 patterns I was searching for. So I then created an awk function to improve my code, however now it wont work. What I am doing is...

```
printFmt () {
    awk -v MYPATH="$MYPATH" -v FILE_EXT="$FILE_EXT" -v NAME_OF_FILE="$NAME_OF_FILE" -v DATE="$DATE" -v PATTERN="$1" -v SEARCH="$2" '
        $0 ~ PATTERN {
            rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
            for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
                rec = rec OFS $i
                if ($i ~ SEARCH) {
                    break
                }
            }
        print rec >> "'$MYPATH''$NAME_OF_FILE''$DATE'.'$FILE_EXT'"
    }
' "$FILE_LOCATION"
}
```

and calling with `printFmt "$STORED_PROCS_FINISHED" "/([01])/"`. My code was exactly above except instead of SEARCH it was /([01])/. Is there something with syntax that i am missing?

Comment: You should try omitting the slashes from the regex passed as a parameter; check whether `"([01])"` works.  It should, I think.

Comment: It isn't clear what `$FILE_LOCATION` is.  You set MYPATH, NAME_OF_FILE, DATE and FILE_EXT on the `awk` command line but ignore those settings and make the shell create the file name (rather clumsily).  Either have the shell do it and don't pass the values to `awk`, or have `awk` do it and don't use the shell to do it.  Also, having all those variables passed by 'environment' (loosely speaking) to the function is a bit peculiar.  Are you sure they shouldn't also be parameters to the function call?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler all the -v? Those are defines I have at the top of my code

Comment: Yes, but as you were told on your last question you pass them to awk but then the awk script **doesn't use them**. So either make awk use them or stop passing them to awk.

Comment: The slashes are regexp literal markers in awk (like double quotes for strings) you don't want them in the value (as Jonathan Leffler indicated in his comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins:

```
printFmt () {
    awk -v regexp1="$1" -v regexp2="$2" '
        $0 ~ regexp1 {
            rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
            for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
                rec = rec OFS $i
                if ($i ~ regexp2) {
                    break
                }
            }
        print rec
    }
' "$FILE_LOCATION" >> "${MYPATH}${NAME_OF_FILE}${DATE}.${FILE_EXT}"
}

printFmt "$STORED_PROCS_FINISHED" "[01]"
```

Your use of all-caps for variable names is bad - that's for exported shell variables only.

Don't use the word "pattern" as it's ambiguous, and "search" is meaningless - come up with 2 meaningful names for the variables that I named regexp1 and regexp2.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments:

1. You should omit the slashes from the regex passed as a parameter.  Passing `"([01])"` instead of `"/([01])/"` should work correctly.  I'm not convinced the parentheses are necessary either; just `"[01]"` should work too.
2. You pass values with `-v` to the `awk` script that are not used inside the `awk` script.  You have the shell use those values to create a file name as well. You should either not pass the values to `awk`, or you should not use the shell to create the file name.

Given these comments, I think your code could be:

```
printFmt() {
    awk -v PATTERN="$1" -v SEARCH="$2" '
        $0 ~ PATTERN {
            rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
            for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
                rec = rec OFS $i
                if ($i ~ SEARCH) {
                    break
                }
            }
            print rec 
        }
        ' "$FILE_LOCATION" >> "$MYPATH$NAME_OF_FILE$DATE.$FILE_EXT"
}

printFmt "$STORED_PROCS_FINISHED" "[01]"
```

Unless the constructed file name changes on each invocation of the function, I would create the file name once, outside the function, and use it outside the function:

```
printFmt() {
    awk -v PATTERN="$1" -v SEARCH="$2" '
        $0 ~ PATTERN {
            rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
            for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
                rec = rec OFS $i
                if ($i ~ SEARCH) {
                    break
                }
            }
            print rec 
        }
        ' "$FILE_LOCATION"
}

OUTFILE="$MYPATH$NAME_OF_FILE$DATE.$FILE_EXT"

printFmt "$STORED_PROCS_FINISHED" "[01]" >> "$OUTFILE"
…7 other calls to printFmt each with I/O redirection…
```

Or even:

```
{
printFmt "$STORED_PROCS_FINISHED" "[01]"
…7 other calls to printFmt…
} >> "$OUTFILE"
```

On the whole, I'd probably pass the file(s) to be scanned as an argument to the function too:

```
printFmt() {
    pattern="${1:?}"
    search="${2:?}"
    shift 2
    awk -v PATTERN="$pattern1" -v SEARCH="$search" '
        $0 ~ PATTERN {
            rec = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $7
            for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
                rec = rec OFS $i
                if ($i ~ SEARCH) {
                    break
                }
            }
            print rec 
        }
        ' "$@"    # All the remaining arguments
}

{
printFmt "$STORED_PROCS_FINISHED" "[01]" "$FILE_LOCATION"
…7 other calls to printFmt…
} >> "$OUTFILE"
```

This gives the most flexibility about where the data comes from and goes to.  It allows the function to read its standard input if no file name arguments are supplied.  The `${1:?}` notation will generate an error if `$1` is not set to a non-empty string; it is a crude but effective way of checking that argument 1 (the pattern) was provided to the function.  Similarly with the search argument too.  The error message won't be wonderfully informative, but any message is probably better than trying to proceed when the values were not provided.